# When uploading HTML files to web hosting pad, why won't my images show up?

Tags: html, hosting

I have a website with all coding and appropriate html and file paths for my images. When I run the code through my own testing process, everything works. However, when I upload my html files and picture folders to the hosting site Web Hosting Pad, none of my images show up, instead a black "x" appears. Everything is uploaded and on the site. This is what the website looks like when hosted through Web Hosting Pad [(Web Hosting Pad version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMNSz.jpg) VERSUS what it looks like through my own test [(My Testing Version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSDKd.jpg). I honestly have no idea what or why this is happening, if its a coding problem or something I'm missing in how I'm hosting the site. Please help if you have any knowledge or idea of what I should do! This is what my code looks like for my images. [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt9pG.jpg)

Comment: It can be that the image src path is different. Maybe you can check with WebHostingPad about the media path or something.

Comment: Right click the browser, go to inspect, go to the console tab, and check there the reason why the images are not downloaded. If it says 404, check the path in the console vs the real path on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you save your images as jpg or jpeg?

You image tag is wrong, it's necessary to close it with "/>"